# Pull docker image for different architecture

Tags: docker

I have an air gapped system that I'm running some docker containers on. I'm trying to get some images on it however the system is a different architecture than what I'm running. For a few images (like GCC) I was able to just say `docker pull repo/gcc` and that worked fine, however for some reason when I try to do `docker pull repo/python` I get:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from repo/python
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Is there a way to specify the architecture in my pull request?

Answer (score 122):

With the latest docker, you can specify platform when you're pulling

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 alpine:latest
```

Comment: This is now the best answer.

Also works with `docker run`.

Comment: `docker pull --platform linux/amd64 alpine:latest` works on Apple silicon for me.

Answer (score 59):

Docker from version `20.10.0`+ (released on 2020-12-08) supports explicit definition of the platform via `--platform` tag, e.g.:

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 repo/python
```

Of course, source must contain an image for the requested platform.

Answer for Docker versions before `20.10.0`:

To answer question from the title: you can pull image by digest.

Example: list all supported architectures (manifest):

```
$ docker manifest inspect ckulka/multi-arch-example
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
   "manifests": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 2200,
         "digest": "sha256:6eaeab9bf8270ce32fc974c36a15d0bac4fb6f6cd11a0736137c4248091b3646",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "amd64",
            "os": "linux"
         }
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
         "size": 2413,
         "digest": "sha256:f02e0fd2918a894ecd49d67b802c22082dc3c6424f6566e1753a83ba833b0993",
         "platform": {
            "architecture": "arm",
            "os": "linux",
            "variant": "v5"
         }
      },
...
```

And then pull by digest, e.g. `arm` arch (pulled on `linux` machine):

```
$  docker pull ckulka/multi-arch-example@sha256:f02e0fd2918a894ecd49d67b802c22082dc3c6424f6566e1753a83ba833b0993
```

But you can't run all architectures, so it can be useless when you pull image for different architecture.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly that: [dockerhub image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/debian/library/debian/wheezy/images/sha256-0aca74f533ba976b4cdaa1b963465aa34009cb5d6d9ca03d60bff9acb5580e23?context=explore)
`docker pull <name>@sha256:0aca74f533ba976b4cdaa1b963465aa34009cb5d6d9ca03d60bff9acb5580e23`
with <name> as "debian/wheezy", "debian:wheezy" and just "debian", but just getting errors:
`Error response from daemon: pull access denied for <name>, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'` or similar...

Comment: `But you can't run all architectures` that's slightly misleading. It does depend on the host machine.  A linux host with properly installed [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) can happily run binaries compiled for other architectures as long as qemu supports that architecture. I believe this is installed by default on the Docker for Mac VM (mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/)), I can't speak for windows.

Answer (score 2):

If the image is not multi-arch, you cant unless you emulate your architecture to be of the target architecture of the manifest.

Comment: And there's absolutely no way to get around it?

Comment: Emulation of different archs is built into Docker so that is not the issue (otherwise multi-arch builds would not work, right?). The issue is that to resolve the digest to pull, it looks for the host arch by default. Specifying the difest like Jan suggested solves the issue.

Comment: "emulation" is really trivial on Linux. Just install qemu (`qemu-user-static`).  Then you can run programs compiled for other architectures.  Obviously you need the supporting libraries in the image, but then docker ships the supporting libraries, that's the point of docker.