# How can a .net core web app docker image run on Mac OS?

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

Ok I know I'm being a noob here but I'm trying to get my head around Docker... I've created a simple .net core Web API app that returns some data. I did this in Windows, pushed to gitlab, but then I can clone on Mac and runs fine as expected...

I then create a Dockerfile that includes..

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
```

As I understand it, does the core sdk include the small nano server windows OS? Does that mean that when I use `docker run` on Mac it's actually running the app on Windows - kind of like in a  mini VM on the Mac?

If this is correct, how does docker know to use the windows nano server, rather than a linux image for example?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where did you find information about Nano Server? According to [tag listing](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) `3.1` tag uses Debian 10 OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

Because .NET Core is cross-platform. And docker works on Mac and Windows (theoretically just the way it works on Linux) the image will work just fine on any platform.

mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 is platform dependent. Depending on the architecture you choose to run Docker it'll pick up Windows Nano server or Linux template.

#### Long Answer:

Docker is not a VM technology. It's a Linux feature that provides you an isolated environment. Docker is not possible on Windows and Mac.
Docker uses Linux features and plugs in an application (and it's related dependencies) in the Linux environment and creates an illusion of resources (network, RAM, disk, software frameworks) needed for running the application.

On windows and Mac. Docker installs a Linux VM. And runs the Docker infra inside the VM.

commands like `docker info` will give more details. This picture below shows that it's running on Linux.

[image]

Switching to Windows docker will give a different output for `docker info` command.

[image]

Comment: I have a docker file that was created on windows, and it starts with```FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443``` but when building the image on my mac, I get this error: `image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform`. Any idea how to resolve it? Should the dockerfile be modified to have the .Net Core app work on mac too?

Comment: docker pull `name:tag` is an interesting combination. When you don't specify tag it indicate latest image. when you say tag is 3.1 it specifically gets 3.1 (but still cross platform) but when you specify `3.1-nanoserver-1903` it fetches windows platform specific  image. 
Refer platform support from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114854/pull-docker-image-for-different-architecture

Comment: Your point actually resolved my issue! (I didn't see anything in the link though)