# Way to pull x86 docker pull & push image on an arm machine?

Tags: docker, x86, push, pull

Is there a way to push and pull x86 image working on an arm machine? I just want to pass through an image for testing.

Comment: Does [Pull docker image for different architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114854/pull-docker-image-for-different-architecture) answer your question?  There is a `docker pull --platform` option, though it doesn't look like there's an equivalent `docker push` option.

Comment: Pushing for a specific platform seems to be dictated by a tag then a manifest, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337210/is-it-possible-to-push-docker-images-for-different-architectures-separately